# How to calculate total of one field in the store

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4

I have a grid within a form as in the attached image.  When the the customer name is changed, then the grid store is loaded with records corresponding to the customer.  I want the balance textfield to be populated with the sum of Amount due column.

The image is  [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?210737-Grid-in-a-form&p=815471).

Answer (score 5):

Use like this:

```
store.load({
    scope   : this,
    callback: function(records, operation, success) {
        //here the store has been loaded so you can use what functions you like.
        //This code sum numbers in certain column
        sum = 0; 
        store.each(function (rec) { sum += rec.get('NameColumn'); });
    }
});
```

Comment: @haddas thanks for the response. Now am facing the problem of posting the grid records through the form panel. Do you have any idea of how this can be done.

Comment: If you satisfied with this answer - please mark it as answer and post another question. I don't see how your additional question is related to this one

Comment: you want something like [this](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/form/form-grid.html)?

Answer (score 3):

Use the store summary function:

```
var sum = grid.getStore().sum('NameColumn');
```

sencha api: [sum store](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-sum)